# I want to store the input from the user such that it can be brought back upon request

Tags: javascript, html, user-input

This is everything I have so far. I want to be able to take the input from the user, store it, then once the user inputs their name, whatever it is, and clicks the claim button, to return the initial input PLUS the interest gained. The coin flip is just another part of the project I'm going to add at the end. I know how to do that already.

```html
<html>
<head>

</head>


<body>

<h1>"Enter how much of your asset your would like to stake and click submit"</h1>

<form id="demo" onsubmit="greet(); return false;">
  <input id = "name" placeholder="Asset" type="text"/>
  <input type ="submit"/>
</form>

<h1>"Enter your name and click claim rewards to withdraw yo money!"</h1>

<form id="demo" onsubmit="claim(); return false;">
  <input id = "name" placeholder="Account Name" type="text"/>
  <input type ="submit"/>
</form>

<h1>"Also, if your feeling lucky, why not try guessing heads or tails?"</h2>

  

<script>
function claim(){
  alert('Enjoy your prosperity!');
}

function greet(){
  alert('Your staked assets will now accrue interest until such time as you withdraw them or there are no more rewards to earn!');

const accrueInterest = 1000;
let asset = 0;
while (accrueInterest){
  console.log(`There are ${asset} gaining interest.`)
  asset++;
  if (asset === 1000){
    console.log("There are no more rewards to earn!");
    break;


    }
  }
}


</script>

</body>
</html>
```

THANK YOU IN ADVANCE FOR EVERYONE'S TIME AND CONSIDERATION!

Comment: This might help you [Local Storage](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Window/localStorage)

Comment: I'm a bit confused honestly about how you want these stored. Do you want this stored forever, or only during the given session?

Comment: This is just a project I'm trying to finish for an academy I'm in, this doesn't need to be permanent, just during the given session will work fine. Sorry for not being more specific.

Answer (score 0):

can you just grab the input by document.getElementById('YOUR INPUT').value, and set this to some variable to call for later use?